# Compare pair of attributes using "IN"

Tags: jpa, jpql

The domain that I'm describing is not the same that I use (with this in mind, there is no need to worry with the fact the the sample class doesn't use Enum for the type, and other things), but describe well my problem. I want to make a query that filter transactions by username and type.

```
public class Transaction {

    private String userName;
    private String type;
    private BigDecimal value;
    ...

}
```

I would like to search all the transactions that match a list of [{'username', 'type'}], where the couple {"username", "type"} is chosen by the user, and the user can choose as many as he wants

For instance: Find all :

- "Debit" transactions made by "Rafael"
- "Credit" transactions made by "Daniel"
- "Debit" transactions made by "Monica"
- "Credit" transactions made by "Monica"

I have two possible solutions for my problem, but I don't like any

> **POSSIBLE SOLUTION 1**

I could dynamically add ***n*** "OR" clauses to my query, like:

```
"WHERE (t.userName = 'Rafael' AND t.type = 'Debit')
       OR (t.userName = 'Daniel' AND t.type = 'Credit')
       ... "
```

> **POSSIBLE SOLUTION 2**

I could concatenate the "username" to the "type" and check if the result is contained by a list of concatenated values of "username" with "type" which was generated dynamically.

```
CONCAT(t.userName, '-', t.type) IN (list)
```

for the example, the variable "list" would have the following values:

```
['Rafael-Debit', 'Daniel-Credit', 'Monica-Debit', 'Monica-Credit']
```

---

I'm using **JPA**, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Solution 2 is pretty clever. Can't see a downside to it.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not so sure if is a good idea, I fear that Solution 2 will generate a lot of overhead doing the concatenation. I'm not even close to be an expert on data sources, and JPA, so I may be wrong. I was hoping that maybe there is a native way to compare Arrays, in this case, List of Arrays, something like that